# NextJs Internationalization for static app built with next export

Tags: next.js

How can I make pages like `/en` , `/th/` for build created by `next build && next export` if `i18n` you can't use in `next.config.js` , also , you can't use dynamic routing `[lang].js` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i18n support is not compatible with next export. (SSR - NextJS 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65513435/i18n-support-is-not-compatible-with-next-export-ssr-nextjs-10)

Comment: It doesn't give me an answer to my question, ok I can't use it, but how can I implement lang support with next export

Comment: Manually, with dynamic routes, `[lang].js` and etc

Answer (score 2):

Internationalisation feature now supports static exports

Official docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization#static-generation

Sample code (from docs)

```js
# app/[lang]/layout.js

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ lang: 'en-US' }, { lang: 'de' }]
}
 
export default function Root({ children, params }) {
  return (
    <html lang={params.lang}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hey, do you know whether this will still work with `output: export`? Or is this limited to static rendering but with NextJS as server backend?

Comment: It should because it looks like NextJS will produce the pages at export with html lang={params.lang}. Depending on how many languages you have you should have the same about of html assets/