# Next.js (Typescript) AWS S3 Export Problem

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, next.js, i18next

Greetings to all friends,

We are using Next.js (Typescript) in one of our projects.

We added [i18Next](https://www.i18next.com/) and provided localization on the site.

However, Next.js has mentioned this translation issue in the unsupported section of its site.

We realized this part after we did rapid development :(.

When we want to stand up and publish on AWS S3 side, it gives errors in nexti18translate.
Has anyone had such an experience before?

Or he will be able to throw helpful resources.

By the way, when we create-react-app, the project stands up in its plain form.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what exactly your issue is. Can you please provide more information?

Comment: btw: to load translations from outside (not on filesystem), there are other possibilities: https://github.com/locize/next-i18next-locize

Comment: Do you mean `next export` doesn't support i18n Routing? If so, that's correct - see this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65513435/i18n-support-is-not-compatible-with-next-export-ssr-nextjs-10.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.