# How to deploy an nextjs on cpanel the app uses (i18next for internationalization)?

Tags: next.js, cpanel, web-deployment, i18next, next-i18next

I'm trying to deploy an app build with nextjs on cpanel file manager,I'm using next export command ***so that I can take the **index.html** file and put it in the file manager directory on cpanel dashboard***, but when I run that command (`next export`) I got an error says
`Error: i18n support is not compatible with next export. See here for more info on deploying: https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment`.

when I followed the link but it didn't have any useful info regarding **i18next**.

SO is there a way to deploy my nextjs app on `cpanel` without `next export`?, or should I remove `i18next` package at all and search for an alternative?

Comment: Related: [i18n support is not compatible with next export. (SSR - NextJS 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65513435/i18n-support-is-not-compatible-with-next-export-ssr-nextjs-10).